# W&B Keras callback TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I'm trying a TF model where the input is string tensor as input, my model contains a [TextVectorization](https://dzlab.github.io/dltips/en/tensorflow/textvectorization-preprocessing/) layer for text processing which is available in TF 2.2.

The training fails in W&B callback with the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

When debugging I found that the issue is during the calculation of weights histograms

```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/histograms.py(325)_get_outer_edges()
    323     else:
    324         first_edge, last_edge = a.min(), a.max()
--> 325         if not (np.isfinite(first_edge) and np.isfinite(last_edge)):
    326             raise ValueError(
    327                 "autodetected range of [{}, {}] is not finite".format(first_edge, last_edge))
ipdb> first_edge
b'0'
ipdb> last_edge
b'zurich'
ipdb> np.isfinite('0')
*** TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Here is how I setup W&B callback and run training

```py
wandb_callback = wandb.keras.WandbCallback(log_weights=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=config.epochs, shuffle=True, verbose=1, callbacks=[wandb_callback])
```

I tried to create the callback with `wandb.keras.WandbCallback()` and not have the weights logged but same issue, it keeps trying to calculate the histogram and fails at the end of an epoch.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your actual model code?  It looks like the model itself contains string tensors.  Normally you would convert the strings to embeddings before passing through the network.  Are you using TensorFlow 2?

Comment: Yes it is, I've updated the description, I'm using TextVectorization layer for in-graph text preprocessing.